# Deductive system for natural language

Tags: logic, metalogic

The formal language of maths use the first order logic to deduce a theorem from a hypothesis. But, in the natural language, the subyacent logic can´t be first order logic. In natural languages all mathematicals are  right with the  existence of a standard model for arithmetic. The term "standard" can´t be translated to logic of first orden, and it implies, for example, we have infinite true phormulas for the natural numbers that can´t be deduced from Peano Axioms and any axioms in first order logic. What is the subyacent logic for natural languages?

Answer (score 1):

You can see releted papaers in :

- Richard Montague, [Formal Philosophy : Selected Papers](https://books.google.it/books?id=nUZxnQEACAAJ) (1974).

You can see [Categorial grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorial_grammar) and [Typelogical Grammar](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/typelogical-grammar/) with bibliography.

See e.g. :

- Glyn Morrill, [Type Logical Grammar : Categorial Logic of Signs](https://books.google.it/books?id=2oP1CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1994)
- Richard Moot & Christian Retoré, [The Logic of Categorial Grammars : A deductive account of natural language syntax and semantics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_-25BQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2012).