# Formalizing Natural Languages

Tags: logic, reference-request, formal-languages, online-resources

I've been interested in the subject of metalanguages and how (if) we can formalize them. Most metalanguages I've encountered use some variation of a natural language (such as English, German or French). Therefore, a relevant question is "how can we formalize natural languages" or at least, certain aspects of it. However, there are very few sources (As far as I've seen) that concern themselves with the subject. I've only seen two papers that have dealt with a similar subject, thus far; One from [Richard Montague](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783111546216-007/pdf), and the other from Thomas Graf.

If you could kindly introduce me to references such as papers, books or any resources that deal with this subject itself and/or its prerequisites (such as syntax, semantics, formal languages), I'd be most thankful.

I'm an undergraduate student in my fourth semester; I'm not as familiar as I'd like to be in both logic and linguistics; So, even the most trivial resource would be most useful to me.

Thank you, very much.

Comment: Categorical Grammar and see SEP's entry on Montague Semantics.

Comment: Are you looking for a citation that natural language isn't formalizable? IIRC there are a few standard examples like *someone loves everyone* that have two readings depending on how the quantifiers are scoped relative to each other. Or are you looking for something that acknowledges some of the ambiguities in language and proceeds anyway?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "formalize natural language"? Are you thinking this would make math more rigorous? I'd say the entire field of linguistics is about finding systematic descriptions of natural languages and how they can (and can't) vary.

Comment: @GregNisbet 
I think both sides are equally fascinating. So, if it is possible to introduce references supporting each argument, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Stackexchange also has https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ . Perhaps they could be helpful? I suggest looking into syntax trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) to get started with linguistics.

Comment: @Karl 
I'm not as familiar as I ought to be in linguistics to be able to parse that statement as true or false; However, from my very little understanding of the subject, I can agree that the study of natural languages in linguistics is systematic. However, to me it is not a mathematical system. By asking for resources for this subject, I'm asking for a mathematically formal treatment or system that deals with natural languages.

And yeah, it does seem to me that it would make mathematics more rigorous if we could do such a thing.

Comment: I think most of the content you'd be looking for is in linguistics and is precise enough to be translated pretty easily into a "mathematical" form. Re making math more rigorous: a formal system can't define itself, so all mathematical reasoning necessarily starts with unformalized natural-language communication at some level; arguably it's better to establish a simple symbolic system at that level (like first-order logic or type theory) than a complex natural-language-like one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here are a few directions you may wish to explore for *formalizing natural language*, which is a broad topic. From looking a bit, this question does not appear to be an exact duplicate of an earlier question, but there may be some other questions [such as this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460729/deductive-system-for-natural-language) that will help.

One is *formalized systems that resemble natural language*.

This includes the [Mizar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_system) which is a piece of software that validates proofs written in a syntax that's like a cross between a programming language and mathematical prose. There is a [Proof Assistants Stack Exchange](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) with more information on Mizar and other proof assistants.

One direction might be *studying metalogic*.

Metalogic uses natural language to avoid circularity, but its use of language is different from natural language in other settings. In particular, metalogical *if* is the material conditional, *usually*.

One thing to check out might be the [Open Logic Project](https://openlogicproject.org/) which has a few free and open source textbooks on logic. [Boxes and Diamonds](https://bd.openlogicproject.org/bd-screen.pdf), the book on modal logic, covers some approaches to formalizing the notions of *possibility* and *necessity* (and some other things like time and deontic status). It includes a lot of examples of explicit metalogical analysis using [Kripke frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics).

One direction might be *cataloging the difficulties we would run into if we attempted to formalize natural language*.

Aside from the difficulties with quantifiers mentioned in the comments, such as in the famous example *someone loves everyone*. The connectives themselves like *and*, *or*, *not*, and *if* are tough to formalize. A compelling account of *all of their usages* is elusive.

*The Connectives* by Lloyd Humberstone, has examples taken from natural language of different kinds of phenomena that defy a straightforward encoding in a logical system. This book is quite big and full of technical details about different logics, but the introductory sections on the chapters about specific connectives have good examples of natural language use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Gellish family of formalized natural languages provides something of interest to you.
It includes an English and Dutch taxonomic dictionary of concepts. Its definition starts with a few bootstrapping concepts that are used to define further concepts in a defined syntax.